# Статическая линковка пользовательских библиотек и библиотек Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Сложно задать вопрос, однако, начну.

**Задача:** нужно написать приложение (любое на Visual c++, но НЕ С++/CLI) с подключением lib файла, а на выходе получить один лишь exe, который бы запускался на любом компьютере с ОС Windows, имел в себе Lib файл (написанный пользователем, например), и не требовал бы наличия библиотек Visual Studio.

Для нашего конечного проекта, к которому мы подключили lib-файлы, нужна статическая линковка. Конкретнее, в настройках проекта  нужно выставить: <kbd>C/C++</kbd> -> <kbd>Создание кода</kbd> -> <kbd>Библиотека времени выполнения</kbd> для отладочной версии /MTd, для релизной - /MT.

Хорошо, теперь рассмотрю 2 случая, из которых вытекают мои вопросы.

**Случай 1: Мы пишем свой Lib файл**

Тогда как компилировать свой Lib файл? Нужно также скомпилировать его с /MTd или /MT или можно как-то иначе?

**Случай 2: Мы работаем со сторонней библиотекой, которую нашли в интернете и подключили** 
Если lib файл, написанный нами мы можем как-то пересобрать, то что делать в этой ситуации?

**Еще вопрос:** 
А если lib-файл вообще скомпилирован на другом компиляторе, например, MinGW, то есть ли вообще возможность подключить библиотеку к нашему проекту?

Надеюсь, я смог выразиться понятно. 
Если кто-то сталкивался с подобным, опишите подробно процесс линковки.

Варианты в стиле: "зачем lib? Сделай dll", отпадают априори!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. По идее, компилируйте lib-файл с /MT или /MTd, в зависимости от платформы. В любом случае на этапе генерации lib-файла линковка не произойдёт.
2. Если у вас сторонняя библиотека, которая идёт в виде исходников, то соберите её в lib, да.
3. Lib, собранный другим компилятором, скорее всего не подойдёт, т. к. на lib (в отличие от DLL) нету бинарного стандарта. Если есть исходники, перекомпилируйтесь под Visual Studio.

Comment: Какой-то у Вас неуверенный ответ :) В первом никаких идей: для MT и MD используются разные макросы, и студия помещает в объектник упоминание библиотеки, с которой ему надо линковаться, поэтому, хотя линковки и не происходит, эти флаги должны соответствовать обязательно. По 3-му: совершенно точно не подойдут, т.к. объектные файлы даже разных студий могут не работать друг с другом, а тут MinGW

Comment: @ixSci: Я уже давно не работал с нативным кодом, так что позабыл тамошние проблемы :) MinGW _могла бы_ генерировать совместимые имена хотя бы для `extern "C"`-кода, но вроде бы она даже этого не делает. (Но не поручусь.)

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то даже `extern "C"` не поможет: к примеру, пусть у нас будет одна функция, в которой есть `wchar_t` и мы приплыли: в студии он 2 байта, а в gcc — 4

Comment: @ixSci: И то правда. Язык без бинарного формата, грабли на каждом шагу.

Answer (score 3):

Да, собирать статическую либу (*.lib) нужно тоже со статической линковкой, как и все либы, которые ей нужны. По крайней мере у меня так работает и никакие msvcrt*.dll не нужны.

lib от других компиляторов могут и не подойти, кстати.